# mean function returns NaN when used in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, nan, mean

I'm trying to build a shiny app and I've never done this before.

The data will be uploaded to the app by the user in this format:

```
Date        Time1            Time2
01/02/2018  01/02/2018 01:02 01/02/2018 01:04
01/02/2018  01/02/2018 02:03 01/02/2018 02:06
01/02/2018  01/02/2018 03:04 01/02/2018 03:08
01/03/2018  01/02/2018 01:05 01/02/2018 01:10
01/03/2018  01/02/2018 02:06 01/02/2018 02:12
01/03/2018  01/02/2018 03:07 01/02/2018 03:14
```

I want the app to select only the earliest date in the date range and compute the mean number of minutes between the two time intervals (3 minutes in my example). The output will look like this:

```
Average Time (in minutes):
3
```

Here's my code:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),
sidebarPanel(
fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
          accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
'.csv')),
mainPanel(
 textOutput('text1')
 textOutput('text2')
 )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 filedata <- reactive({
 infile <- input$file1
 if (is.null(infile)) {
  return(NULL)
 }
 namedDF <- fread(infile$datapath)
 names(namedDF)[c(1:3)] <- c("Date", "Time1", "Time2")
 return(namedDF)
})

 output$text1 <- renderText({
 "Average Time (in minutes): "
 })

 output$text2 <- renderText({
  myDF <- filedata() # read the uploaded data from reactive
  myDF$Date <- as.Date(myDF$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y") 
  sortedByDate = myDF[order(myDF$Date)]
  day1 = as.Date(sortedByDate$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")[1]
  namedDF <- sortedByDate[sortedByDate$Date == day1,]
  #convert tender, pickup, depart, arrival and delivery to time objects
  timesData = namedDF[,c(2:3)]
  timesData$Time1 = as.POSIXct(timesData$Time1, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", 
   tz="GMT")
  timesData$Time2 = as.POSIXct(timesData$Time2, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", 
   tz="GMT")
  #compute length of interval, add to original data frame
  interval = 
   as.numeric(difftime(timesData$Time2,timesData$Time1,units="mins"))
  newDF = cbind(namedDF,interval)
  names(newDF)[4]<-c("Delivery.Mins")
  #remove cases with missing records
  newDF_n = na.omit(newDF)
  #clean data
  newDF_n[,4][newDF_n[,13] < 0] <- NA
  newDF_n[,4][newDF_n[,13] > 999] <- NA
  #remove cases with bad data
  newDF_o=na.omit(newDF_n)
  averageTime = mean(newDF_o$Delivery.Mins, na.rm = TRUE)
  averageTime
})
```

When I run this it returns NaN instead of the number 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might just have a few typos. E.g. `sortedByDate = myDF[order(myDF$Date)]` should be `sortedByDate = myDF[order(myDF$Date), ]` and I am not sure what you are trying to do with the two lines below `#clean data` . I was not able to get your app running as is because I didn't use the `fread()` function but commenting out the two clean data lines and fixing the type seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are correct: I did have a typo, and it was in the lines under "clean data." I put in the wrong column numbers. I put in those lines to remove values under 0 or over 999, as these values are errors and I do not want them included when computing the mean. Changing the column numbers to the correct ones solved the problem.